# How can I know if my iOS App is running on my device or in any other?

Tags: ios

I know that have 2 properties on UIDevice class

```
uniqueIdentificer - with is no longer available in iOS 7; and

identifierForVendor - with is only available in iOS 6 and above...
```

How can i know if is my app running the app or any other device?
I need this app running from iOS 4.3 to 7.1

i.e.:

```
if (isMyDevice) {
  // Run this code
} else {
  // Run that code
}
```

tks guys

Comment: You could use different tests depending on the iOS version number.  Or you could abandon UUIDs altogether, and test for, say, a login ID#.

Comment: but checking the udid is not allowed in app store anymore

Answer (score 0):

Use this if statement, and inside them check if the udid is yours or not:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] < 7.0) {
}
else {
}
```

Comment: but checking the udid is not allowed in app store anymore

Comment: Are you sure? I thought it just returned garbage data on iOS 7.